# Excel - Search for Match Value

Tags: excel

May I know how to search for a match value and only display one time only? For example:

```
A         B          C (will search for match and display one only)                                 
GHI      2          XXY        
XXY      3          
XXY      5
```

I am able to output the match value but it will also display the duplicate value. For example, `XXY` will display twice in column C. Here is the code that I did

`=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MATCH($A1,$A$1:$A$10,))`

Comment: Index/Match displays the first match only. It will NOT display any duplicate values. Are you asking how to display multiple matches?? It is not clear what your question really is, since you already have a formula for what you describe you want to achieve. You may want to use FALSE as the third parameter in MATCH if you want an exact match. Leaving it blank defaults to TRUE, which may not return what you expect. Also, the formula will return GHI, not XXY.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question. What I mean is to display multiple matches. For example, in column A has multiple `XXY`. Column C will display the multiple matches that will be `XXY`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Excel 2016 use CONCAT formula with IF. IF you are using earlier version you need to create UDF. as below

```
Function ConcatUDF(Rng() As Variant, ByVal delim As String) As String
Dim a, I As Long
For I = 1 To UBound(Rng, 1)
    If Rng(I, 1) <> "" Then
    ConcatUDF = ConcatUDF & _
        IIf(ConcatUDF = "", "", delim) & Rng(I, 1)
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Here are the examples to use it.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. When creating the UDF, can i create any name or I need to use ConcatUDF? Sorry but I am still new in excel especially using formulas

Comment: yes. you can give any name other than the names of built in functions.